# Carga CPU IOS Swift

Tags: swift, objective-c, iphone

necesito saber la carga de la CPU % del iPhone pero no encuentro nada ni en Swift ni Objective-C. He encontrado algo que me % que usa la aplicación del total de la CPU. Alguien me podría ayudar con información o algo.

Gracias

Comment: ¿Cuando te refieres a la carga de CPU, te estás refiriendo a lo que consume la app que estás desarrollando?

Comment: No lo que consume todo el sistemas con app todo en completo. Cuando vas a Monitor de Actividad y hay sale la carga completa de la CPU eso quiero en iOS.

Comment: Ne es eso. Quiero hacer una app de información del dispositivo. Lo que aparece Activity Monitor - > CPU lo quiero sacar por código para plasmarlo en la app. Gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: @Bodgan He actualizado mi respuesta con un link donde se explica como sacar la info

Answer (score 2):

La forma más simple es utilizar Instruments. Lo puedes encontrar en el siguiente menú:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde ahí, eliges la opción "Activity Monitor" y podrás verlo todo.

Por otro lado, al ejecutar la aplicación tienes un "pseudoinstruments" integrado en el propio Xcode:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez en ese apartado, puedes clicar en "CPU", "Memory", etc y podrás ver un panel de control donde ver el estado de la app en todo momento de la ejecución.

**UPDATE 1:**

Si en cambio lo que quieres es sacar la info directamente en a la app puedes utilizar este enlace que lo explica y es un buen punto de partida: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223348/ios-get-cpu-usage-from-application

De todas formas, cuidado porque que Apple haya aprobado una aplicación, no quiere decir que ahora te la acepte en la AppStore

Comment: Lo que quiero sacar es la info de lo que consume los demás procesos mas mi app